# Changing port of xampp caused project url leads to 404

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

Port 80 is occupied by system. SO I changed the default port(80) of xampp apache server to port 81. It is working and only thing changes in my url is, I have to type port number in url like this to make it work

```
localhost:81/phpmyadmin  //example
```

But When I transfer my one codeigniter project to my pc in xampp then all link tag urls started to show as 404. My css wasn't getting picked. Here is the url in link tag were like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

When I inspect and rightclick on `href` in link tag and click on option `Open in new tab` then in new tab, following url open

```
localhost/project_name/css/style.css       //PORT number is missing
```

But this should have open like this

```
localhost:81/project_name/css/style.css
```

Why my codeigniter project link is not picking `localhost:81` but instead it is picking only `localhost`. Any idea?

Comment: Have you added port number in config.php's base_url?

Comment: "localhost:81/project_name/" this should be your base_url

Comment: @IDon'tKnow Ohh yes, I didn't change it. Now when I tried to change it then it worked fine. Thanks.. Please type your solution as answer. i will accept it :)

Comment: My pleasure... XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have changed the port number then you need to change the base_url in config.php. In your case it should be.

`localhost:81/project_name/`